# Creating multiple rows in a SQL table from a source table that has summarised data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `t_times` that looks like this

| start_time | End_time | Number_of_slots | Slot_Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00 | 09:00 | 6 | 10 |
| 09:00 | 09:30 | 1 | 30 |

I need to create a table using the values in the `t_times` to create `t_slots`

| start_time | End_time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00 | 08:10 | 10 |
| 08:10 | 08:20 | 10 |
| 08:20 | 08:30 | 10 |
| 08:30 | 08:40 | 10 |
| 08:40 | 08:50 | 10 |
| 08:50 | 09:00 | 10 |
| 09:00 | 09:30 | 30 |

In essence for every value specified in the number_of_slots field I need to:

- Create a new row in the target table
- Add the corresponding time slot (start and end) using the duration taking into account the slot_duration field's value. I.e. for a value of 6 I need to add 6 rows with ten minute increments each that uses start_time as the starting value

I can do it with a cursor but it seems a very roundabout way of doing this. Can someone please point me in the SQL direction? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is `start_time` and `end_time` a `time`? Can you have a period that spans over midnight?

Comment: They are indeed times. I didn't add the full date time as I just needed a pointer for the SQL to start me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main idea here is to use classic approach with number table. It is quite common to have such table as a persistent one, so the one won't need to generate it on run time. It's a common tool for analytical stuff as yours.
Second is JOIN it with the source one on the right predicate.

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists src
go

create table src (
    start_time  time
    ,End_time   time
    ,Number_of_slots int    
    ,Slot_Duration int
)
go

insert into src values
('08:00',   '09:00',    6,  10)
,('09:00',  '09:30',    1,  30)
go

;with nums as (
    select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as n
    from sys.all_columns
)

select start_time, dateadd(MINUTE, n*Slot_Duration, start_time) as end_time
    , Slot_Duration as Duration
from src 
join nums on src.Number_of_slots >= nums.n
order by start_time, end_time
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained what your code did. Encouraging best practices (and identifying them) would also be a great help. In particular - the use of statement terminators is a best pactice to use for **every** statement, not just one. When used, you don't need to use the "beginator" as you did with a CTE - which is just a lazy kludge to avoid using terminators consistently.

Comment: I expect copy pasting code from the web isn't the best practice either. This is a template  anyone can adjust it to its needs. ps old habits are die hard

Comment: Thank you for the feedback freebench. This code points mee exactly in the right direction!!